# How to use tree shaking for node modules with Webpack 5?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, tree-shaking

I want to boost my website performance. I recently see an error on unused javascript from lighthouse.

I checked the bundle and apparently those unused javascript are actually being used from other modules and node packages which I have been download.
For example, `@sentry/node` is what I'm using, but report shows unused javascript from `@sentry/hub`. But I only did install on `@sentry/node` but not the whole `@sentry` package. Further more, `@sentry/node` is using `@sentry/hub`, but I'm not importing `@sentry/hub` anywhere in my code (which I assume that causes the problem)

I have included  `"sideEffects": false` to my `package.json` file but nothing seems to work

Comment: You find a solution, running across same thing with another package.

Answer (score 0):

You could try destructuring, target only the object (or function) you are using.

e.g.

```
import { Component } from 'react';
```

Therefore, for you...

```
import { yourFunction } from `@sentry/node`;
```

Or simply take the code `@sentry/node` that you are using. ‍♂️

Otherwise, show your code:

- package.json
- webpack.config.js
- your "index" file (where you import your scripts and other files)
- the file you import `@sentry/node` in